# Stupid Algebra Mistake Somewhere in an Easy Bernoulli DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a straightforward DE but I know I am making some simple mistake somewhere in the middle of this problem. An extra set of educated eyes would be appreciated, thanks.

Solve the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y - y^{3}$$

$\frac{dy}{dx} - y = y^3$ substitute $u = y^{-2}$ ; $y= u^{-1/2}$; $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{2} u^{-3/2}\frac{du}{dx} $   yielding

$\frac{-1}{2}u^{-3/2}\frac{du}{dx} -u^{-1/2} = -u^{-3/2}$ Multiply this equation by $-2u^{3/2}$ yielding $\frac{du}{dx} + 2u = 2$ This is now a simple 1st order linear equation.

Setting $\mu=e^{\int2dx} = e^{2x}$ giving $2ue^{2x} = \int2e^{2x}dx$ ||$2ue^{2x}=e^{2x} $ || $2y^{-2}e^{2x}=e^{2x} $ finally finishing with $y^{2}= 2 +c$

The posted solution is $y^2 = 4 +\frac {e^{2x}}{c}$ if it helps

Comment: You mean $dy/dx - y = -y^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote
$\frac{dy}{dx} - y = y^3
$.

It should be
$\frac{dy}{dx} - y = y^{-3}
$.

Comment: Just a typo, checked through my work. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in this part :

[image]
(Not clear enough to be more specific)

$$\frac{du}{dx}+2u=2 \quad \text{  is OK.}$$

An obvious particular solution is $u=1$

The solution of the homogeneous part of the ODE $\frac{du}{dx}+2u=0\quad$ is $\quad u=c\:e^{-2x}$

Thus, the general solution of the ODE is : $u=c\:e^{-2x}+1$
$$y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{c\:e^{-2x}+1}}=\pm\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{c+\:e^{2x}}}$$